# "I wish I could" or "I wish I could have"

Tags: subjunctives

> I wish I could do it.

> I wish I could have done that.

The second seems off.

What do generally use with wish sentences. And is there any specific title we can use to dictate sentences with wish kinda meaning?

Comment: Can you give an example context for using these? To me, they have different meanings from each other depending on context - so neither is preferable by default.

Comment: 'I wish I could play the piano' (you desire the ability to do something). 'I wish I could have gone on that trip to London last week' (you regret missing the opportunity). Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present Continuous/Past Perfect

Your focus is on the word "wish" when actually all becomes clear if you dispense with it:

"I could do it" / "I could have done it"

Both sentences are fine, and "wish" can be incorporated pretty much anywhere you wish!

Answer (score 0):

> I wish I could do it.

is to regret about something you can't do in the present.

> I wish I could have done that.

is to regret about something you weren't able to do in the past.